# Java noob - drawing text

Tags: java

I took two open source games to learn how to overlay text onto one of the games from the other.  however, whenever i try to transition one piece of code from the next all i get is exceptions.  to make sure im drawing a string correct im using :

```
import java.awt.*;

public class charge{


    Image buffer;
    Graphics bufferg;

    public void draw2(Graphics g2d){

        g2d.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 13));

        g2d.drawString("Most relationships seem so transitory", 20, 30);

    }
```

}

can anyone tell me how im using graphics wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the graphics class correctly is very tricky, especially if you're new to java. It's likely that the error your getting is a null pointer, because your g2d arg is probably null. One (preferred) way to draw text in java is to subclass the JPanel class and override the paint(Graphics) method so whenever the panel is drawn, it's drawn with text. Here's an example:

```
public class Test1 extends JFrame {

 public Test1(){
    TextPanel t = new TextPanel("Here's some text!");
    getContentPane().add(t, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

    //Various JFrame initialization stuff. 
    //repaint() makes sure the text is immediately visible.
    repaint();
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

  class TextPanel extends JPanel{
    private String text;

    public TextPanel(String t){
      text = t;
    }

    //Called by swing whenever this or a parent component calls repaint()
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
      g.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 13));
      g.drawString(text, 20, 30);

    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    new Test1(); 
  }
}
```

If you want to use the text for overlays then just make sure the background of the TextPanel is transparent and place it wherever you want to on the window.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i still find it a bit confusing, any links you can link me too to read up on it ?  thanks